# Easy way to validate XML File

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I have a C++ program, where the user can pic a .xml file in which tracks are stored. Basically these files are .gpx files with a minor change so the pugixml can read it. How can I make sure that the file the user selected has the right format? It is for example important, that the `<name>` is `Track x` and that the node names are right.
This is an example of such a file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<trk>
    <name>Track 1</name>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="48.08162894291554" lon="11.274891365644537">
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="48.08167553246409" lon="11.274872590181431">
      </trkpt>
  </trk>
  <trk>
    <name>Track 2</name>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="48.08162939089216" lon="11.274952385899628">
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
</trk>
```

Is there an easy way to validate the form of an .xml file? Or do I have to check manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two ways to validate `xml` files:

- Using a `<!DOCTYPE … >` [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition),
- Using an XML schema  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C))

Both validation methods should be handled by the parser. Which method to choose depends on the level of granularity you need for validation, whereby XSD (Schema) is more sophisticated and on what is available for you. So if there is a DTD (Doctype Definition) is available, is might be more "easy" to just use that. You can of course write some code which does the validation, too, but I guess that is not the "easy way" you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question @philipp, but how do I use DOCTYPE? I place `<!DOCTYPE Root SYSTEM "doctypedefinition.dtd">` underneath the `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` part and write a seperate file with the name `doctypedefinition.dtd` which specifies which node has to come in which order?

Comment: And then I tell pugixml that it should check with `node_doctype` if the document uses the doctype `Root`?

Comment: @A.Hue U have updated the wikipedia link, since this was in german by mistake. You can find the detail in there. It would be a kind of too much, to explain all the details here

Comment: @A.Hue The validation is done by the XML Parser, I do not know which one you are using, so it depends on that how to tell it: "validate against this doctype". But you can always "insert" the DOCTYPE into the xml, if not already present.